# NODE.js Insert no MS SQL

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, conexão

Eu estou tentando executar um INSERT no meu MSSQL através do meu servidor NODE.js
Mas ele não está funcionando.

Eu acredito que não é um problema de conexão porque (como demonstrarei no final do post) eu fiz um select que funcionou.

então devo estar cometendo algum erro no código node.js

Este é o primeiro sistema javascript que eu criei.

```
    var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    var body = req.body;
    var sql = require("mssql");

             console.log("C1");
     sql.connect('mssql://login:senha@servidor/banco', function (err) {

        if (err) console.log(err);

        // create Request object
         console.log("Connected!");
        var insert = "INSERT into dbo.WIDS_API_TEST (Programm, ID, Titlw) VALUES ('Teste 1 2 3 ', '39', 'Finance')"

        // query to the database and get the records
        sql.query(insert, function (err, result) {

            if (err) console.log(err)

            // send records as a response
        console.log("1 record inserted");

        });
    });
});

//var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
  //  console.log('Server is running..');
//});
```

O que estou fazendo de errado? Porque o INSERT nem sequer mostrou meu console.logs = /

Quando eu fiz um teste fazendo um select funcionou

```
   var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    var sql = require("mssql");

    // config for your database
/*    var config = {
        user: 'papercut',
        password: 'Portage.2018',
        server: 'devsqlcl2:1433', 
        database: 'AgrM6',
        port: "1433",
        dialect:",ssql",
        dialectOptiond:"SQLEXPRESS"
    };*/

    // connect to your database
    sql.connect('mssql://loginh:senha@server/banco', function (err) {

        if (err) console.log(err);

        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();

        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query('select * from dbo.balance_papercut', function (err, recordset) {

            if (err) console.log(err)

            // send records as a response
            res.send(recordset);

        });
    });
});

var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

!! ESTE FUNCIONOU, É O SELECT!!

Comment: Verifique se o usuário que utilizou para conexão com o banco de dados WIDS possui permissão para ler (gravar) na tabela `WIDS_API_TEST`.

Comment: Tem sim, realziei esse teste ja , direto no banco e funciona, atualizei a pergunta para ficar mais facil e menos confusa

Comment: Qual o erro que é mostrado? Vou reescrever esse seu código para ficar menos confuso

Comment: Dá uma olhada no código que vou postar aqui no comentário e informa na sua pergunta o erro que for retornado no console, mas a principio o nome das suas colunas está errado https://pastebin.com/X5xL8pdX

Comment: A resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que os nomes das suas colunas estão incorretas, porém sem a mensagem correta de erro fica praticamente identificar o problema. Portanto reescrevi seu código de uma forma levemente mais legível e com um tratamento de erro que irá mostrar no `console` qual foi o problema ocasionado:

```
const express = require('express');
const sql = require('mssql');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
// Cria o pool de conexões do banco
const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool({
  server: 'devsqlcl2',
  database: 'AgrM6',
  port: 1433,
  user: 'papercut',
  password: 'Portage.2018',
}).connect();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/', async ({ body }, res) => {
  try {
    const resultado = await pool.request()
      .input('programm', 'Teste 1 2 3')
      .input('id', '39')
      .input('title', 'Finance')
      .query('INSERT INTO dbo.WIDS_API_TEST (programm, id, title) VALUES (@programm, @id, @title');

    console.log('Linhas afetadas', resultado.rowsAffected);

    res.send(resultado);
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
    res.status(500).send('Erro interno');
  }
});

const server = app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('Server is running..');
});
```